# How can I apply bsxfun like functionality at Eigen?

Tags: matlab, eigen

Suppose I have a matrix A which is n x n matrix and I have a vector b which is n x 1 vector and I want to calculate the following implementation in Eigen library.

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, A, b)
```

How can I apply it Eigen ?

Comment: Scroll down to *Broadcasting*: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf A(n,n);
Eigen::VectorXf b(n);

A.cwiseQuotient( b.replicate(1,A.cols()) )
```

Here is one without replication, equivalent to `bsxfun` in MATLAB:

```
A.array().colwise() / b.array()
```